Creating a process in a thread, can we?, should we?
Can/should we crate a new process in thread in, say, Unix? That is, we execute a fork() in a thread?
Thanks!

Yes, you can use fork(). The POSIX documentation includes a description of what happens and what the limitations are when called from a multi-threaded program.

Thank you Shawn! The short answer, according to the document, really is -- yes you may, but don't. Thanks!

Some might say.... 'how could it be possible on any other way?'
